# closing FileInputStream object throws exception

Tags: java, ioexception, fileinputstream

When I want to close InputFileStream and OutputFileStream objects, eclipse says that I need to catch IOException so here is my code after catching those exceptions.
As you can see I am catching IOException twice. Is there a more simple way that I can have only one block for catching IOException for both in.close() and in.read() ?

```
public class ByteStream {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FileInputStream in = null;

    try {

        in = new FileInputStream("testdata.txt");
        int nextByte;
        while((nextByte = in.read()) != -1){
            System.out.println(nextByte + "-");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null){
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: `try-with-resources`.

Comment: What does e.printStackTrace() says?

Comment: There is no error and everything works fine. I just want to make the code simpler by using only one IOException block.

Comment: As a matter of fact, [yes](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/clean-up-after-yourself.html).

Comment: Do what @SotiriosDelimanolis said...but just wanted to add that's 1.7+ only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax in Java 7

```
try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("testdata.txt");){

    int nextByte;
    while ((nextByte = in.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.println(nextByte + "-");
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the compiler will take care of converting the above code to code that closes the `in` `InputStream`, or any other `AutoCloseable` object declared and instatiated in the `()` part of the `try` expression.

Comment: It is one way. Still looking forward to see solutions regrading Java 6.

Comment: @iman You won't find any. What you are doing is the correct java 6 way of doing it.